# Return Children (of known, but different classes) from the Parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**Background**

I'm looking to be able to go from a parent class, and show me all of the children that it has, but the children may be of a set of ***specified and known, but different classes***.

Here's an example of the setup:

```
class Basket < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :apples
  has_many :pears
  has_many :oranges
end

class Apple
  belongs_to :basket
end

class Pear
  belongs_to :basket
end

class Orange
  belongs_to :basket
end
```

I know that I can do this - one by one for each specific fruit - which is already supported in Rails, through Active Record.

`Basket.pears #=> [ Pear:0x007fd6ec615fd8, Pear:0x343d6e343495fd8 ]`

**Actual Question**

**But I want to be able to go from the parent Class (ie `Basket` in this example), and show me all the children in one go (ie `Apples`, `Pears`, `Oranges`)
We could call the grouping of these children as `fruits`...so something like this:**

`Basket.fruits #=> [ Pear:0x007fd6ec615fd8, Pear:0x343d6e343495fd8, Apple:0x343d6e343495fd8, Orange:0x343d6e343495fd8  ]`

**Also I want it to return an `ActiveRecord_Relation` so I can do things like:**

`Basket.fruits.where(fruit_seasonality: 'Fall') #=> [ Orange:0x007fd6ec615fd8 ]`

(assuming that all of the children classes in `fruits`, have an attribute called `fruit_seasonality` on them)

**What I've tried:**

```
class Basket < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :apples
  has_many :pears
  has_many :oranges

  def fruits
     apples + oranges + pears
  end
end
```

Which is cool, then I can do `Basket.fruits`, but this just returns an `Array` which doesn't help for the queries, like `Basket.fruits.where` etc.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need single table inheritance (STI).

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :basket
end
class Apple < Fruit; end
class Pear < Fruit; end
class Orange < Fruit; end
class Basket < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :apples
   has_many :pears
   has_many :oranges
   has_many :fruits
end
```

For this you need a table `fruits` with a column `type` instead of 4 separate tables.

Comment: I don't want a single table inheritance, because the fruit models differ considerably in their attributes (I guess the example used wasn't as ideal as it could have been to support this though)

Comment: In this case take a look at polymorphic association. Use a intermitate model between basket and fruits and this  uses  `belongs_to :fruit, polymorphic: true`.